# does db2 have identity insert on?

Tags: sql, insert, db2, identity

I have table with identity, seed 1 auto increment 1. In that table I have rows with primary key 1,2,4,5 (3 is missing, I deleted it), now I want to insert values in that table but with ID of 3, but I can't find it how in db2...

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  There's a limited set of situations where you have to track all ids, and you're generally not allowed to delete them in the first place.  Most of the time, nobody cares about missing ids, because there's too many ways for them to disappear.

Comment: I'm studying for exam, it's more for my knowledge and database understanding. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how the column is defined. If it is `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`, then you can simply provide an explicit value for it in the `INSERT` statement. If the column is `GENERATED ALWAYS`, you could temporarily restart the identity sequence from the value you need, perform the insert, then restart it again with the maximum value + 1. The latter will only work if there is no concurrent insert activity on the table, of course.

Having said all that, I think that if you really require a gapless identity sequence you should not be using autogeneration in the first place.

Comment: It is generated always as identity... But when I try insert into and put explicit value it won't work.